# Adding drop-down text to segments of a Blend(-ed)4web plane?

Tags: interface, export, add-on, text-object

Can anyone give advice regarding the Blend4wed exporting formats? 
I am basically hoping to export out a simple plane which will allow certain interactive features i.e. when a viewer hovers over an allocated segment of this plane, a segment of text will drop down with information about this specific component. The plane will also hopefully contain zoom/ pan features to further support this text component. Is this output even possible?
Advice would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Nice to see a blend4web question! Unfortunately I have no idea. :-/

Comment: Thanks anyways dude, hopefully someone may know how to! :)

Comment: You certainly can achieve this behavior but it will require a bit of JavaScript coding. If you will have further questions feel free to ask for help on the Blend4Web forum.